# Is there a bug in numpy when using the += operator

Tags: python, numpy

When using a function in phyton, I am taught that actually a copy of my value is parsed. In the example shown below apply a function onto a Parameter a. Here, I expected that a copy of a is sent to the function fun. In this function, only the copy of a is available, not parameter a on a global scope. I even gave it another Name: b. When I modify the value b in my function, then also the Parameter a on the global scope is changed. Is this supposed to be correct?

```
import numpy as np

def fun(b):
    b += np.array([1,1])

a = np.array([1,1])

fun(a)

print(a)
```

I expected to get `np.array([1,1])`, but I get `np.array([2,2])`

This happens only, when I use the += Operator in the function fun. If I use `b = b + np.array([1,1])` instead, the value of a on global scope stays the same.

Comment: In `def fun(b)`, the paramter `b` was passed in by reference. While you run the following, you will understand the issue:

```
import numpy as np


def fun(b):
    print(['in def fun(b)', id(b)])
    b += np.array([1, 1])


a = np.array([1, 1])

print(id(a))

fun(a)

print(id(a))

print(a)

```

Comment: @Till Hoffmann the [duplicate] mark is kinkd of wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `fun()` you don't make a copy of `a` and modify `b`, rather, `a` itself is passed to `fun()` and refered to as `b` in there.

As such,

```
b += np.array([1,1])
```

modifies `a`.

Answer (score 0):

In python the list datatype is mutable, that means that every time you run your function, a list will keep growing.

**The key moment is here:** `b += np.array([1,1])`

You already got `a`, which is `[1, 1]` and you adding it to another array which is `[1, 1]` and you are getting `[2, 2]` which is how it should be.

You are ending up modifying the `a`